# Missing data from structure

Tags: c++

I don't know why single data missing from structure but others not, here your are structures

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint32_t            size;
    u_long              crc32;
    char                flags;
    char                filename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
} update_file_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t            magic;
    uint32_t            num_files;
    update_file_t       files[MAX_FILES];
} update_into_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

// Reading part
update_info_t *upd = (update_info_t *)chunk.memory; // Downloaded by CURLib
update_file_t *files = &upd->files[0];
files->filename // it's always NULL WHY?
files->crc32    // correct
files->size     // correct
```

I don't know what is wrong, maybe CURLib downloading it wrong?
Server generate the file correctly

```
    update_file_t       *file;
update_info_t       upd;
char                file_src[256];
update_file_t       *loc_file;

memset(&upd, 0, sizeof(upd));
upd.magic       = magic;
upd.num_files   = 0;

if (!(Out = fopen(output, "wb"))) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't open the output file for writing" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

for (int c = 0; c < UPD_MAX_FILES; c++) {
    file = &upd.files[c];

    memset(file->filename, 0, sizeof(file->filename));
    file->crc32 = 0;
    file->flags = 0;
}
loc_file    = updgen_file_list;
file        = upd.files;

while (loc_file->filename && loc_file->flags) {
    if (upd.num_files >= UPD_MAX_FILES) {
        std::cout << "UPD_MAX_FILES exceeded!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(file_src, sizeof(file_src),  "%s/%s", path, loc_file->filename);
    if (!(file->size = CRC32FromFile(file_src, &file->crc32))) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't calculate checksum for " << loc_file->filename << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    strncpy(file->filename, loc_file->filename, sizeof(loc_file->filename));
    file->flags = loc_file->flags;

    std::cout << "Added file " << file->filename << ", size: " << std::dec << file->size << " bytes, crc32: " << std::hex << file->crc32 << std::dec << std::endl;

    upd.num_files++;
    loc_file++;
    file++;
}
if (fwrite(&upd, sizeof(upd), 1, Out) != 1) {
    std::cout << "Failed writing the update info to the file!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This is server part code, I don't know what is still wrong

Comment: *How* do you check the members? And what do you mean by `files->filename` being `NULL`? Technically speaking it's not a pointer and can't be `NULL`, but it can be *empty*.

Comment: It cannot really be `NULL`, it's not a pointer. It has a specific address in memory.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, its empty, but still don't know why

Comment: It's empty because it's what's you've received from CURLib. The mystery is why it was stored like that on the other side.

Comment: @detunized added server code

Comment: All this C++ and you're still using stuff like `char[256]` instead of `std::string`? Yikes. Overflow bugs ahoy.

Comment: Do you really have both `update_into_t` and `update_info_t`? Or are you giving us a hand-written approximation to the real code? It would be very helpful to give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) so that we can see what's really going on without guessing.

Comment: @tadman char x[SYMBOLIC_CONST] is perfectly valid C++ and quite different in meaning from std::string x;   Try sending structure containing an std::string through a socket.  You won't be pleased with the result. [note the word "downloading"]

Comment: @DaleWilson You can convert a C++ `std::string` to a C `char*` with the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method. Try it, you'll be pleased with the result. Fixed length buffers for strings have no business being in a C++ program. If you spend the small amount of time it takes to write a proper C++ stream interface for your structure, this is totally transparent. If you're dumping the whole buffer to the socket, regardless of length, you've got other problems.

Comment: @tadman: If you have control of both ends of the connection and if you are willing to sacrifice performance and if you have time to redesign your protocol to support variable length strings, yes, you can let the string class and the new support code you have to write take care of the overrun issues.   Your comment is unhelpful when you blanket condemn anyone who uses a char[] in C++, without addressing the OP's question.  And for the record, use std::string::data(), not std::string::c_str() for this purpose. [last response from me: we're way off-topic]

Comment: @DaleWilson `data` does not always return a `NULL` terminated string, `c_str` does. Anyway, there's barely a question here to answer, so I'm just giving feedback on the obvious issues. I'd rather deal with `string` conversion than the bugs that happen with buffer overruns because of sloppy coding. `strncpy` and friends are world of hurt, and where you can avoid it completely, such as you can in C++, **do it**.

Comment: Ok, the problem is resolved, the problem was in serialization flag: #define PACKED __attribute__((packed))